# Cannot perform Setup Project Uninstallation

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I get following message in my installation log when trying to uninstall application created with .NET Setup Project

***MSI (s) (F0:C4) [16:00:16:532]: Product: "Product Name" -- Configuration failed.***

Another version of this product is already installed.  Installation of this version cannot continue.  To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.
{some GUID in here}

Comment: If you are incrementing the version number, but using the same GUID for your product, I think you run into this issue. I'm not sure, as I usually use Wix for my MSI projects.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like your registry got messed up.

You can use the following [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296067) to manually remove the application

If your GUID is 00000409-78E1-11D2-B60F-006097C998E7 for example, just run the following line
to remove the program

```
msiexec.exe /x {00000409-78E1-11D2-B60F-006097C998E7}
```

good luck!

Comment: What should i do when i don't know the GUID ?

Comment: @eugeneK you mentioned that an error message appears and the GUID is inside it.

Comment: Shai, i do that in C# by accessing cmd via WCF service installed on machine.

Comment: Why? do you also try to uninstall the application using a WCF service? this is a MANUAL fix for your problem... everything is possible though, even uninstalling an application from a remote host using the GUID.. you can find the list of GUIDs on your host in the registery, under SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Comment: Yes, i do uninstall and then install of application via WCF service as i automate installation of this application on n machines.